# how to get the value from Array[String:Array] in swift

Tags: ios

How to get the get from the below JSON format.I have an data in this way......

```
 data:[{location:[{id:1,name:sam}]}]
```

So how to get the name from this data...
I try with as below....

```
 if let location = data["location"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{
    print(location)
 }
```

here i got as:

```
  -[[id:1,name:sam]]
```

output when print(location)

From here i need to get the name how to get the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go deeper into structure

```
if let location = (data["location"] as? Array<[String:Any]>).first, let str = location["name"] as? String {

    print(str)
}
```

The best way would be to map it to Structures straight from JSON

Comment: i need not to print.i need to put to the string.thatis i need in this way self.place = location["name"] as? String

Comment: i have edited answer, but your example didnt show that you want it in string, i believe you know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Now use below code

```
for dict in location{
  print("id: \(dict["id"]), name: \(dict["name"])")
}
```